# Is it possible to add a subquery table to a django queryset?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset, drf-queryset

I am working on a query similar to the one below; I want to create this as a Django queryset for further filtering.

```sql
select distinct on (id) id, title, weight
from (select *, 3 + ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector(title), to_tsquery('sales'), 32) as weight
      from courses
      where to_tsvector(title) @@ to_tsquery('sales')
      union all
      select *, 2 + similarity(title, 'sales') as weight
      from courses
      where title % 'sales') as union_table
order by id, weight desc
```

I tried creating it as `raw` method, but that doesn't allow chaining additional filters and the `extra` method with the `tables` argument doesn't allow [subqueries](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7907).

Is there any solution other than using the raw SQL?

Comment: [django union](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#union)

Comment: @IvanStarostin django union cannot be combined with distinct